# run vmware-player image with java

Tags: java, vmware-player

Is there way to run specific VMWare-player image (assuming that it was created beforehand, and name is known) from java application?
Maybe there exist some libs already, but i wasn't able to find them. Or better if some one could post code snippet.

In other words i want invoke VMware player to run a image from java.

Comment: Can i know what is your actual purpose for running the image in java? Or you wanted to invoke VMware player to run a image from java?

Comment: "invoke VMware player to run a image from java"
 - 
yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this not for production and realtime systems, it can be done by kicking [VMWare commands](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_learning_cli_vmrun.html) from java.lang.Runtime 
Some thing like: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start abc.bat");

Comment: if i understand correctly there is vmrun for workstation, but it is not available in Player version

Comment: @KonstantinPetrukhnov  try my other updated answer, using the -T option

Comment: i also need to fix bug for player 4.0.2: http://minuteware.net/vmware-player-and-vmware-vix-the-specified-version-was-not-found/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply invoke the VM player then use the following. To invoke the player with vmrun use `-T`

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec("<path-of-installation>/vmrun -T player start <name-or-path-of-image-file>");
```

Or if you want to do any study on the running Vm Player then [VMware Infrastructure (vSphere) Java API](http://vijava.sourceforge.net/)  might be useful.

Comment: I just add that vmrun could be downloaded as VMware VIX package.

Comment: ya.. after getting that package you have to implement the code as above to invoke the player.